# How to query a query using date field inside a metadata of type JSONField?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

How to query a query using date field inside a metadata of type JSONField?

In the field metadata of my line contains the following content

```
[
        {
            "id": "57400265c48f4ae16ea6f719bb360",
            "method": {
                "id": "be32754f6c3643c49c308a4526646",
                "expiration_date": "2019-06-12T00:00:00+00:00",
                "accepted": false,
                "printed": false,
                "downloaded": false,
                "created_at": "2019-06-12T11:49:00+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-06-12T14:48:59+00:00"
            }]
```

I tried to use a query with range to return values of data between two dates.

```
Transac.objects.filter(id=request.user.id, metadata__method__expiration_date__range=(datetime.date(2019, 7, 1), datetime.date(2019, 7, 30)) )
```

I also tried using the gte

```
Transac.objects.filter(id=request.user.id, metadata__method__expiration_date__gte=datetime.date(2019, 6, 1) )
```

Nothing worked. The error follows.

```
TypeError: Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable
```

If anyone can help, I'm very grateful.

Comment: Is your field `metadata` type JSONField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the django json encoder date format:

```
metadata__method__expiration_date__gte = "2019-06-12T11:49:00+00:00"
```